# ImageJ: runPlugIn (Fill Holes) with a ImageProcessor

Tags: java, imagej

In ImageJ there is the Posibillity to fill Holes (in Binary Pictures). I want to use such a plugin in my plugin:

```
IJ.runPlugIn("Fill_holes", "");
```

But this didn't work.. and I don't want to use it on the original picture. I want to use it on the eddited picture in the ImageProcessor (I have a binary mask and want to fill all holes).

Is that possible or can somebody please help me out?

Comment: I solve it: binaerpic.unlock();
  IJ.run(imp, "8-bit", "");
  Prefs.blackBackground = false;
  IJ.run(imp, "Make Binary", "");
  IJ.run(binaerpic, "Fill Holes", "");

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).